# MySQL-Simple Query take 11 seconds to return results

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have mysql query that takes the products from a table (6k+ records) and join another table that holds the images for those products (5.5k+ records) and in where I choose to select the products form specific vendors. Below is the query.

```
SELECT  *
    from  products
    LEFT JOIN  products_images  ON (products.id = products_images.product_id)
    WHERE  products.vendor_id in (
        SELECT  id
            FROM  vendors
            WHERE  status=1      )
```

I need help with optimizing this query. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` often produces better execution plans:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p LEFT JOIN 
     products_images pi
     ON p.id = pi.product_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM vendors v
              WHERE p.vendor_id = v.id AND v.status = 1
             );
```

You also want indexes on `product_images(product_id)` and `vendors(vendor_id, status)`.

If I assume (reasonably) that `id` is the primary key in `vendors`, then you can also use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*, pi.*
FROM products p JOIN
     vendors v
     ON p.vendor_id = v.id LEFT JOIN 
     products_images pi
     ON p.id = pi.product_id
WHERE v.status = 1;
```

For this version, the best indexes are probably:  `vendors(status, id)`, `products(vendor_id, product_id)`, `product_images(product_id)`.

Comment: Yes id is primary key in vendors table.

Comment: It means you don't care about the value, you just want the row to show up.

Comment: @MajidAli . . . An `exists` clause returns true if any *rows* are returned in the subquery.  The columns don't matter.  "1" is easy to type and is not misleading.